# top/bottom:[%] based on parent element's borders instead of height

Tags: html, css, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

I found a weird behavior when positioning a child element using top:[%]. On mobile-safari, given top/bottom borders of sufficient size, the behavior seems to switch: Instead of the percentage being applied to the parent's **height**, its applied to the parent's **borders** (plus a little extra).

The following code reproduces the bug:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 100px;
  
  width: 100%;
}

.normal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.defective {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

* {
  /*style reset*/
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="normal">
      <p>The top is 10px</p>
    </div>
    <div class="defective">
      <p>I should be at the same height</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In this example, the top should be 10px, but when I inspect the element, it's actually 20.3px. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Here is what I see]

Other details:

- The bug seems to kick in when the sum of the vertical borders of the parent are 98% or more of its height.
- The child element doesn't have to be a div, it can be an image.
- The bug does NOT appear if the child has `position:absolute`.

Am I the only one who sees this? Is is documented somewhere?

Reproduced on the following:

- iPhone XS Max 12 (real device on browserstack.com)
- iPad mini iOS 9
- iPhone8, with Safari 13.6 (simulated on lamdatest.com)

Comment: Your snippet is working fine for me on Safari on iPad IOS 14. Tested with an img as well as with a div and with several % settings. Is there any more detail you could add? Perhaps a screen shot of the problem on a real device with an image so we can see it.

Comment: I'm updating the snippet to be less succint, but to make it instantly clear if the "bug" is present. I'll add a picture of what I see as well. I don't have access to a real iOS device with me.I used a free trial at browserstack to access the iPhone XS Max 12. It's supposed to be a real device.
Thank you for your quick reply. I wish I could have gotten back to your even quicker.

Comment: Snippet still looking fine on iOS iPad so I guess I have to increase some dimension to see the bug. What is ‘ the sum of the vertical borders of the parent are 98% or more of its height.’ is it the sum on the heights of the horizontal borders?

Comment: "is it the sum on the heights of the horizontal borders?" Yes it is. I noticed I got the same result if I put `border-top:200px` or both border-top and border-bottom at 100px (but NOT only 1 at 100px).

 "I guess I have to increase some dimension to see the bug."
There is more than likely another hidden variable indeed.

I'm guessing you don't have access to another iOS device yourself. It might be fixed on mobile-safari 14. Or do you suspect it's a simulated device problem? I personally don't see a reason to doubt the claim that browserstack uses real devices, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: Yes, I’ve just tried it on an old iPad mini iOS 9 and the bug shows. so it may be IOS14 has cured something or that the newer iPad is too large a screen size, though if you don’t see it on small windows that’s not so likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relatively placed element is displaced vertically depending on the width of the border on some versions of IOS. This did not show on an iPad running Safari IOS14 but did on a mini iPad running IOS 9.

This appears to be a bug in at least some IOS versions.

A workaround might be to put the border into a pseudo element on parent. This snippet then worked on IOS 9 on the mini iPad:

```html
<style>
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  
  width: 100%;
}
.parent::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border-bottom: 200px;
 border-style: solid;
}
.normal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  
  rdisplay: none;
}

.defective {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

* {
  /*style reset*/
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    
    <div class="defective">
      <p>I should be at the same height</p>
    </div>
    <div class="normal">
      <p>The top is 10px</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'll put this as the accepted answer, even if there are still details missing. I find it wild that this bug is so obscure/unkown. It caused me a lot of frustration.

Anyways, thank you for your thoroughness. In my specific use-case, I did not need this work-around, because I could simply use the margins instead of the border. I hope this helps a next soul.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I couldn’t find anything on lists of bugs on IOS that were known, but something has changed in the more recent versions.